# How can I exclude all except a specific css class?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

This is the HTML markup:

```
  <q-expansion-item disable>
    <template v-slot:header>
      <q-btn label="click"></q-btn>
    </template>
    <q-card>yo</q-card>
  </q-expansion-item>
```

I have this sass which I can't change:

```
.disabled, [disabled]
  &, * 
    outline: 0 !important
    cursor: not-allowed !important
```

I have this sass which aims to override the above:

```
.q-item
  &.disabled
    opacity: 1.0 !important
    .q-btn
      cursor: pointer !important
    &, *:not(.q-btn)
      cursor: default !important
```

The intent is that all items except `.q-btn` will get the default cursor, while `.q-btn` will get the pointer cursor. It doesn't work though. It seems that the `:not` modifier doesn't work with the `*` selector.

Here's the JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/noeldacosta/pdo1k9Lt/20/

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Is that syntax fine for SASS? Post the compiled CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was insufficient specificity.

This works:

```
.q-item
  &.disabled
    opacity: 1.0 !important
    button.q-btn
      cursor: pointer !important
    &, *:not(.q-btn)
      cursor: default !important
```